# Catching exceptions on launching SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
@ImportResource({"classpath:batch-job.xml"})
public class BatchApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchApp.class, args);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

At the backend I have a db configuration:

```
<bean id="cryptoUtil" class="com.batch.util.CryptoUtil">
        <property name="userId" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
        <property name="key" value="123456789012345678901234"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" primary="true"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver.classname}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.meta.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="#{cryptoUtil.userId}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{cryptoUtil.password}" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="batchMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.batch.mapper.batchMapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

When there are any connectivity issues, I get the error:

> Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection
>   with the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently
>   know of service requested in connect descriptor

in the line:

```
SpringApplication.run(BatchApp.class, args);
```

I want to catch this exception to display it in the batch UI. When I tried with :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchApp.class, args);
        }
        catch(NetException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

the IDE shows, suggesting to convert to throws declaration or removing the catch clause.

Please help on how this can be done.

**UPDATE**:
*Stack trace*:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-11 15:36:47.029 ERROR 13712 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Spring Batch
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.batch.BatchApp.main(BatchApp.java:21) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Spring Batch
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.initialize(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:101) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:369) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:327) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:355) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:100) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:183) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:131) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.initialize(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:96) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:318) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:272) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    ... 44 common frames omitted

Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Spring Batch
```

Comment: can you put the error stack trace?

Comment: What's wrong with catch(Exception e) ?

Comment: @NawnitSen: Updated Nawnit

Comment: Because I get a generic error: `Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Spring Batch` for whatever exception @Rahul

Comment: The stacktrace does not contain anything about "converting to throws declaration" or removing the catch clause. Those seems IDE **suggestions** not errors

Comment: Yes. IDE suggestion @Giacomo. Updated

Comment: catch `SQLRecoverableException` this exception in try catch.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are expecting to catch is thrown at a different location:
**oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection**

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:272) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
```

From there onwards, the error/exception is being caught and a different exception/error is being thrown in different Spring, DB driver, etc APIs. The final one being:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Spring Batch
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
```

This is the error/exception you will get at:

SpringApplication.run(BatchApp.class, args);

In short, you can't catch oracle.net.ns.NetException the way you are doing in your code.